# How do you close a view from another view in .net maui?

Tags: c#, .net, maui

I am trying to implement a loading/is busy logic in my app. When the item is selected from a collection view it shows a popup of a activity indicator which works fine. But, I am unable to close the popup once the other view loads. I have tried calling Close() but that doesnt do anything. So pretty much just trying to figure out the best way to show a activity indicator then close it once the process is done.

```
async void ItemSelected(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var popup = new LoadingPopup();
        this.ShowPopup(popup);
        var item = e.CurrentSelection.FirstOrDefault();
        if (item != null)
        {
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new YearPage(item) {BindingContext = item });
            
            //await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new YearPage
            //{
            //    BindingContext = item
            //});
        }
    }
```

Calling close on the popup from a different view page(as the method doing the work is on a different page and I want to close the popup once it is done) doesnt work.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/views/popup#programmatically-closing-a-popup

Comment: I added a public void as well, public void ClosePopup() => Close(); and I tried calling it from another view and it runs the line but it never closes the view also (I dont want to user to be able to close it as its a loading indicator). Is there a better practice of this then what im trying to implement?

Comment: are you calling it on the same instance of `LoadingPopup`?

Comment: I would assume not as I am unsure of how to do that. What would be the best way to do that from another view? (Apologies I am a little new to this)

Comment: you would have to pass a reference to the other view

Comment: I apologize I'm a little confused on what kind of reference I would pass, would it be possible to give a super simple example? Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: is `YearPage` the **other** page you want to dismiss the popup from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to pass a reference to the popup to the 2nd page

```
var popup = new LoadingPopup();
this.ShowPopup(popup);
var item = e.CurrentSelection.FirstOrDefault();
if (item != null)
{
  await Navigation.PushAsync(new YearPage(item, popup) {BindingContext = item });
```

then you would have to modify the `YearPage` constructor to accept that 2nd parameter

then you would have a public method on `LoadingPopup` to dismiss via the `Close()` method